# BIML: Issues about Datatype-Handling on ODBC-Source Columns with varchar > 255

Tags: ssis, biml

I'm just getting into BIML and have written some Scripts to creat a few DTSX-Packages. In general the most things are working. But one thing makes me crazy.

I have an ODBC-Source (PostgreSQL). From there I'm getting data out of a table using an ODBC-Source. The table has a text-Column (Name of the column is "description"). I cast this column to varchar(4000) in the query in the ODBC-Source (I know that there will be truncation, but it's ok). If I do this manually in Visual Studio the Advanced Editor of the ODBC-Source is showing "Unicode string [DT_WSTR]" with a Length of 4000 both for the External and the Output-Column. So there everything is fine. But if I do the same things with BIML and generate the SSIS-Package the External-Column will still say "Unicode string [DT_WSTR]" with a Length of 4000, but the Output-Column is telling "Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]". So the mapping done by BIML differs from the Mapping done by SSIS (manually). This is causing two things (warnings):

1. A Warning that metadata has changed and should be synced
2. And a Warning that the Source uses LOB-Columns and is set to Row by Row-Fetch..

Both warnings are not cool. But the second one also causes a drasticaly degredation in Performance! If I set the cast to varchar(255) the Mapping is fine (External- and Output-Column is then "Unicode string [DT_WSTR]" with a Length of 255). But as soon as I go higher, like varchar(256) it's again treated as [DT_NTEXT] in the Output.

Is there anything I can do about this? I invested days in the Evaluation of BIML and find many things an increase in Quality of Life, but this issue is killing it. It defeats the purpose of BIML if I have to correct the Errors of BIML manually after every Build.

Does anyone know how I can solve this Issue? A correct automatic Mapping between External- and Output-Columns would be great, but at least the option to define the Mapping myself would be ok.

Any Help is appreciated!

Greetings
Marco

*Edit* As requested a Minimal Example for better understanding:

- The column in the ODBC Source (Postegres) has the type "text" (Columnname: description)
- I select it in a ODBC-Source with this Query (DirectInput):
  `SELECT description::varchar(4000) from mySourceTable`
- The ODBC-Source in Biml looks like this:
  `<OdbcSource Name="mySource" Connection="mySourceConnection"> <DirectInput>SELECT description::varchar(4000) from mySourceTable</DirectInput></OdbcSource>`
- If I now generate the dtsx-Package the ODBC-Source throws the above mentioned warnings with the above mentioned Datatypes for External and Output-Column

Comment: I'm a touch confused - are you using source queries like `SELECT CAST(MyWideColumn as varchar(4000)) AS TruncCol FROM pgTable` or LEFT would work there as well. Or are you attempting to specify the length of your columns in the ODBC Source's extended properties (exact Biml property eludes me)? Can you provide a minimal repro of what you're experiencing?

Comment: I added the minimal example for future reference. Please tell me if it's sufficient in your opinion. But I got a solution from another direction which I will post here in a few seconds for any other who runs in this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment before I got an answer from another direction:

You have to use DataflowOverrides in the ODBC-Source in BIML. For my example you have to do something like this:

```
`<OdbcSource Name="mySource" Connection="mySourceConnection">
  <DirectInput>SELECT description::varchar(4000) from mySourceTable</DirectInput>
  <DataflowOverrides>
    <OutputPath OutputPathName="Output">
      <Columns>
        <Column ColumnName="description" SsisDataTypeOverride="DT_WSTR" DataType="String" Length="4000" />
      </Columns>
    </OutputPath>
    <OutputPath OutputPathName="Error">
      <Columns>
        <Column ColumnName="description" SsisDataTypeOverride="DT_WSTR" DataType="String" Length="4000" />
      </Columns>
    </OutputPath>
  </DataflowOverrides>
</OdbcSource>`
```

You won't have to do the Overrides for all columns, only for the ones you have mapping-Issues with.

Hope this solution can help anyone who passes by.

Cheers